# Syncing SharePoint workspace over https

Tags: sharepoint

Currently, my sharepoint setup allows me to sync a site with SharePoint workspace over HTTP, but not over HTTPS. When adding new workspace, if I type

http://sharepoint.mycompany.com

then everything syncs without problem.

However, if I type

https://sharepoint.mycompany.com

I am greeted with this pleasant error message - SHarePoint workspace was unable to interpret the SharePoint location. Please check and ensure the location contains no typing errors.

I should mention that I am currently using a self-signed ssl ceritificate. But when the workspace is first syncing, it already asks me whether to trust the connection and proceed. Does anyone know how to sync SharePoint workspace over https connections?

Comment: Any ideas? Has anybody successfully setup sharepoint workspace over https before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Getting a signed security certificate for SP workspace, and then set the SharePoint central administration public path to include https solves the problem. Really obnoxious to fix, but eventually did work.